# Convergence in distribution implies convergence of CDF

Tags: probability, measure-theory, weak-convergence

We know that If $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables with PDFs $f_n$, such that $f_n(x)$ converge pointwise to $f(x)$ for almost all $x$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$

My question is when do we have the converse implication.
I think I have read somewhere that if the CDF of $X$ is continuous we do get the converse implication.

What are the other cases?
And do you have an example where this is false?

Comment: Use $f_n(x)=F'_n(x)$, whenever it exists.

Answer (score 0):

> do you have an example where this is false

$f_n(x) = (\sin n x + 1)\mathbf{1}_{[0,2\pi]}(x)$. The corresponding distributions converge to the uniform law, but the pdfs diverge almost everywhere.